# reference need about History of prime number development

Tags: reference-request, notation, number-theory

Im trying to connect my study to a breif history of prime numbers . Also im interesting in reading history of numbers how they come and how they developed .
So can any one suggest for this question a good book or
any helpful reference for the history of prime numbers from Creek till 19 century and thank you in advanced .

Comment: Look at Narkiewicz's "The Development of Prime Number Theory from Euclid to Hardy and Littlewood." It probably has more than you could possibly want to read.

Comment: Dickson's classic [History of the theory of numbers](https://archive.org/stream/historyoftheoryo01dick#page/n17/mode/2up) is available online.

Comment: Thank you , just little question is there any book form 1900 till present in the development of primality testing and divisibility .@KCD @conifold

Comment: I don't know about a book, [Bornemann's PRIMES Is in P](http://webhome.csc.uvic.ca/~ruskey/classes/326/fea-bornemann.pdf) in Notices briefly reviews some of it prior to Agrawal-Kayal-Saxena.

Answer (score 4):

- Oystein Ore, [Number Theory & its History](https://archive.org/details/NumberTheoryItsHistory) (1948)
- André Weil, [Number Theory: An approach through history From Hammurapi to Legendre](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ar7gBwAAQBAJ&pg=PR7) (1984).